# Issue with mod_rewrite apache | redirecting non www url to www url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect all request on my site to url of format:

```
https://www.mydomain.com
```

as I have SSL certificate for `www.mydomain.com`. I have written following rewrite rules in my `httpd.conf` file to do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
RewriteRule $ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule $ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Out of the following possible formats, only one is not working:

```
mydomain.com - working
www.mydomain.com - working
http://mydomain.com - working
https://mydomain.com – not working
https://www.mydomain.com - working
http://www.mydomain.com - working
```

Can anyone explain the reason behind and solution for this issue?

**Update:**

When I try to hit the URL which is not working (`https://mydomain.com`), I get an invalid SSL certificate error (as my certificate is valid for `www.mydomain.com` and not `mydomain.com`) and hence none of my Rewrite rule is getting executed as http connection is not yet made.

Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the certificate that I have. Try https://amazon.com and you will see the untrusted connection problem. I have similar issue. Option is to buy another certificate.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to try

```
rewritecond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
```

instead of

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

Comment: This doesn't work as well, Please read my update in question above.